# how to unblock website in c#

Tags: c#, .net

access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts' is denied c#

```
try
  {
      string websiteToUnblock = "youtube.com"; //Initialize a new string of name websiteToUnblock as example.com
      StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"); //Initialize a new instance of StreamReader of name myReader to read the hosts file
      string myString = myReader.ReadToEnd().Replace(websiteToUnblock, ""); //Replace example.com from the content of the hosts file with an empty string
      myReader.Close(); //Close the StreamReader
      StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"); //Initialize a new instance of StreamWriter to write to the hosts file; append is set to false as we will overwrite the file with myString
      myWriter.Write(myString); //Write myString to the file
      myWriter.Close(); //Close the StreamWriter
      Console.WriteLine("asas");
 }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
     MessageBox.Show(e.Message); // show exception in 
  }
```

Comment: If you can not access a file the "normal way" (with file explorer), it is unlikely you can access it at all, unless you bypass the OS' security.

Answer (score 1):

The account credentials your C# is running does not have access to the folder you are requesting. You need to either:

- get your account credentials access
- or run your code with a different account that does have access.

To run your account with different credentials use  **[System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)** or if it is a website change the permissions the app pool run as.

You cannot bypass security. If the website is blocked, you need it to be unblocked for you. Code will not magically bypass security.

Comment: Additionally, run the app as admin may work, but I'm quite sure he doesn't have admin rights on this computer.

Comment: @Haris this is less a solution and more guidance.  My solution will not unblock a website for you but answers your questions why the path is denied.

Comment: how to unblock website in c# ??

Comment: This a bad question for Stackoverflow. Instead, try solving the problem and post coding questions instead.

Comment: @Haris You can't. The website is blocked by your network admin (or your parents) for a reason.

Comment: if you have solution so tell me .. ok